# Can't read nor write from file in c

Tags: c

I'm supposed to make a program that writes, modifies, deletes and searches a list of contacts. We still haven't studied Files but we're supposed to finish this soon. I tried everything but i can't modify or delete or search. Can you help me? Here is my code:

I tried to read the file into a structure so I can use it for the other functions, but somehow it won't read because when I try other functions or search for something in the structure, the function doesn't find it

```
fichier=fopen("liste contact.txt","r");   
 if (fichier!=NULL)
    {fichier=fopen("liste contact.txt","a+");
        while (c=fgetc(fichier)!=EOF)
        { for (i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        fscanf(fichier,"%s %s %s %d %s", &newcon[i].id,&newcon[i].prenom,&newcon[i].nom,&newcon[i].tel,&newcon[i].adr);}
        }   fclose(fichier);}           
    else {fichier=fopen("liste contact.txt","w");
    }
```

In modify, i try to write into a file. but it won't write anything but the new name or something else I modify here. Every other value is empty

```
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
    if (id==newcon[i].id)
    {cn=i;}             }                 
 if (cn!=0)
 {

   switch(d) {
      case 1 :

         printf("         Donnez le nouveau nom: \n --->"); scanf("%s",&newcon[cn].nom);
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {fprintf(f2,"ID: %s, Prenom: %s, Nom: %s, Tel: %d, Adresse: %s . \n", newcon[i].id,newcon[i].prenom,newcon[i].nom,newcon[i].tel,newcon[i].adr);}
         break;
      case 2 :

           printf("         Donnez le nouveau prenom: \n --->"); scanf("%s",&newcon[cn].prenom);
      for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {fprintf(f2,"ID: %s, Prenom: %s, Nom: %s, Tel: %d, Adresse: %s . \n", newcon[i].id,newcon[i].prenom,newcon[i].nom,newcon[i].tel,newcon[i].adr);}
     break;
      case 3 :

         printf("         Donnez le nouveau Email: \n --->"); scanf("%s",&newcon[cn].email);
      for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {fprintf(f2,"ID: %s, Prenom: %s, Nom: %s, Tel: %d, Adresse: %s . \n", newcon[i].id,newcon[i].prenom,newcon[i].nom,newcon[i].tel,newcon[i].adr);}
       break;
      case 4 :

           printf("         Donnez la nouvelle adresse: \n --->"); scanf("%s",&newcon[cn].adr);
        for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {fprintf(f2,"ID: %s, Prenom: %s, Nom: %s, Tel: %d, Adresse: %s . \n", newcon[i].id,newcon[i].prenom,newcon[i].nom,newcon[i].tel,newcon[i].adr);}
          break;
      case 5 :

          printf("         Donnez le nouveau numéro de telephone: \n --->"); scanf("%d",&con[cn].tel);
         for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {fprintf(f2,"ID: %s, Prenom: %s, Nom: %s, Tel: %d, Adresse: %s . \n", newcon[i].id,newcon[i].prenom,newcon[i].nom,newcon[i].tel,newcon[i].adr);}
        break;
      default :
       Beep(3000,900);  printf("L'action que vous demandez n'existe pas, réssayez!" );
 }  }fclose(f2);}
```

Comment: You are testing the result of open before calling open.

Comment: Just a reminder, fixing the indent format in your post would make your codes more readable.

Comment: You are reading c from the file and ignoring the result.

Comment: @stark oh no i've already opened it as fichier=fopen("liste contact.txt","r"); This is my first time asking a question here, sorry!

Comment: Quand vous postez sur stackoverflow, il faut prendre le temps de nommer vos variable en anglais, et de traduire les éventuels chaîne de caractères dans le code. stackoverflow est un site en anglais et il est difficile pour un non francophone de comprendre du code avec une nomenclature francophone. De plus, l'informatique est dominé par l'anglais, vous devriez prendre l'habitude d'utiliser une nomenclature anglaise si vous voulez que votre code soit compris par d'autres que vous.

Comment: Mes études sont en français, c'est pourquoi je dois tout écrire en français pour le moment, je suis désolé, j'éssayerai de changer mes variables.

Comment: @stark i'm sorry could you explain the ignoring the result more?